# Chrome Extensions - How to detect a URL change when the tab doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For instance, in some web applications like YouTube, when you click on a link, the tab doesn't "update" or refresh. hence, the "chrome.tabs.onUpdated" event will not be triggered. How can I detect a URL change when the tab doesn't update?

--Edit, I'm using a Service Worker and not a background script.

Comment: Wrong: chrome.tabs.onUpdated will be triggered so you should simply use it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I really wish it did, but it isn't. are you using a service worker or a background script?

Comment: I just verified it in a MV3 service worker and it works just like it did for the past 5+ years.

Comment: Today, I've seen people doing weird things in MV3 extensions like registering the worker explicitly via `navigator` instead of relying on the automatic registration via manifest.json so maybe you're doing something wrong too. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question maybe.